# CentOS installation of new kernel

Tags: centos, kernel

I have a remote Server with OVH where they have their customized kernel which is causing us a problem while installing our software using CentOS 5.10

While applying the procedure to install the software we are getting the following error.

LOG:

```
1--------[root@ usr]# rpm -Uvh --force emp-2.1.2-0.noarch.rpm
Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
   1:emp                    ########################################### [100%]
Installing...
        Starting emp ...
Not support your kernel 3.14.32/i686/32-xxxx-grs-ipv6-32/emp.ko.
Please contact your technical support.


2--------------- [root@ usr]# service ip6tables stop
Flushing firewall rules:                                   [  OK  ]
Setting chains to policy ACCEPT: raw mangle filter         [  OK  ]
Unloading ip6tables modules: Opening /proc/modules: No such file or directory
grep: /proc/modules: No such file or directory
Opening /proc/modules: No such file or directory
grep: /proc/modules: No such file or directory
                                                           [  OK  ]
```

The feedback of our supplier is to change the CentOS kernel.

What is the procedure to change the kernel, step by step?

OVH is company for Hosting/server Rental. I have the same software working with another kernel 2.6.18-398.el5. the issue is that OVH have their own customized kernel with additional Security and modification that is preventing our software from being installed. this is according to our supplier ( we only need to install either the Original Kernel or a PAE kernel. )

Comment: Welcome to U&L! Could you help make your question a little more clear by expanding the "OVH" acronym? Also, just to clarify, your question seems to be about changing the CentOS kernel; but you may also need some clarification from the supplier as to which kernel version you need to change _to_.

Comment: OVH is company for Hosting/server Rental. I have the same software working with another kernel 2.6.18-398.el5. the issue is that OVH have their own customized kernel with additional Security and modification that is preventing our software from being installed. this is according to our supplier ( we only need to install either the Original Kernel or a PAE kernel. )

Comment: Have you asked OVH this question?  You'll need to ask them to set up the system to boot into a more appropriate kernel.  Hosting companies like OVH run a virtualization service that boots their customized kernel, not the CentOS kernel.